# Running a loop from second line of a file in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I want to use the below file content as an input of for loop my script. As from second line we have id's which will be used to fetch content from db.

```
cat abc.txt 
id
27
27
27
27
23
```

Comment: Is the loop doing something with these numbers that could be done in a single `awk` script?

Comment: Related: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Answer (score 4):

This can get as simple as the following:

```
{ read -r; while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done; } < abc.txt
```

The `{` here means to group the command. Using `read -r` we'll skip the first line!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter it with `sed` before the proc.

for example, instead of `cat abc.txt` you can `sed 1d abc.txt` to remove the first line.

Answer (score 0):

This works - even if the headline is not in the first row or there is an empty line:

```
awk '!/^(id| *)$/{print$0}' file | while read line; do
    something $line
done
```

I used `while` in this example, because it is often preferable over `for`.

That said - here is your `for` loop:

```
for line in $(awk '!/^id$/{print$0}' file); do
    something $line
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the files containing your IDs is in the same directory as this script, this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
content=$(tail -n +2 abc.txt)
for line in $content; do
        echo "$line"
done
```

Output:

```
27
27
27
27
23
```

Comment: I think for large file both answers will break.

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) -- use a `while read` loop instead.

Answer (score -1):

**Not recommended if your file is large**

You can use like:

```
 for i in $(sed -e '1d' abc.txt)
 do
   something
 done
```

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) -- use a `while read` loop instead.